# Calculating margin through mysql query

Tags: mysql

My mysql query is as below which give error

Below is with if else

```
SELECT 
o.id,
p.product_name,
p.admin_price,
co.product_amt_disc,
(co.product_amt_disc + product_vat_disc) AS sale_amount,
(IF co.retake_flag = 1 THEN
    ((co.product_amt_disc - (p.admin_price+6))/(co.product_amt_disc))
ELSE 
    ((co.product_amt_disc - p.admin_price)/(co.product_amt_disc))
END IF
) as margin FROM
customer_orders co
    LEFT JOIN
m_products p ON p.id = co.product_id
    LEFT JOIN
    orders o on o.id=co.order_id;
```

Below on is with case

```
SELECT 
o.id,
p.product_name,
p.admin_price,
co.product_amt_disc,
(co.product_amt_disc + product_vat_disc) AS sale_amount,
(CASE WHEN co.retake_flag = 1 THEN
    ((co.product_amt_disc - (p.admin_price+6))/(co.product_amt_disc))
ELSE 
    ((co.product_amt_disc - p.admin_price)/(co.product_amt_disc))
) as margin FROM
customer_orders co
    LEFT JOIN
m_products p ON p.id = co.product_id
    LEFT JOIN
    orders o on o.id=co.order_id;
```

I am getting below error  for id

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'co.retake_flag = 1 THEN   ((co.product_amt_disc - (p.admin_price+6))/(co.product' at line 7
```

I am getting error for CASE

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as margin FROM     customer_orders co         LEFT JOIN     m_products p ON p.' at line 11
```

I want to calculate percentage on behalf of condition retake flag. please help and let me know if anything else required 
Thanks

Comment: update your question and add  your exact error message

Comment: If syntax is not good : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp, you want a  case/ when here

Comment: @DanielE. i did that too but it isnt working in anyway

Comment: If..else..end if is only available in stored programs.And there are way too many brackets here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing END in CASE statement

the correct answer is as below

```
SELECT 
o.id,
p.product_name,
p.admin_price,
co.product_amt_disc,
(co.product_amt_disc + product_vat_disc) AS sale_amount,
(CASE WHEN co.retake_flag = 1 THEN
((co.product_amt_disc - (p.admin_price+6))/(co.product_amt_disc))
ELSE 
((co.product_amt_disc - p.admin_price)/(co.product_amt_disc) ) END
) as margin
FROM
customer_orders co
LEFT JOIN
m_products p ON p.id = co.product_id
LEFT JOIN
orders o on o.id=co.order_id;
```